# How to avoid line break when one of the child has `width:100%` style

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to horizontally align div elements within a container div element avoiding line break between the child elements.

But, when one of the child div element has `width:100%` style as in the following:

```
<div style="float:left;overflow-x:hidden;background-color:blue;width: 300;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;">1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:100%;">2</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;">3</div>
</div>
```

that element is placed by itself on a new line like this:

[image: actual]

How can I avoid line breaks under any circumstances? When the sum of the child elements' width is greater than that of the parent's width, I want that part of the element to be cut off (hidden). I tried it using `overflow-x:hidden` as above, but it did not work.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wGRnT/1/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want all of the elements to push outside the parent when their sum is greater than the parent? If so, try adding this to the parent:

```
{ white-space:nowrap; }
```

[**View on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LMfrZ/)

This works because the children are set to be inline-block elements, so they're treated like text. Chris Coyier has a good explanation (with pretty diagrams) of all things white-space [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/), which you might find interesting.

Comment: It overflows out of the side of the container and gets hidden. I interpreted this as the behavior that sawa wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this instead of **inline-block** use **table-cell**:

```
<div style="float:left;overflow-x:hidden;background-color:blue;width: 300;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;background-color:yellow;">1</div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;background-color:green;">2</div>
  <div style="display:table-cell;background-color:yellow;">3</div>
</div>
```

result:
[image]
[full display property list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: I think you are right by suggesting `display:table-cell`, but I think I need to add `width:100%`. Your result is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use another DIv but use px widths rather than percentage as using 100% as a width is NEVER going to work afaik.

```
<div style="float:left;overflow:hidden;background-color:blue;width:300px;">
    <div style="width:3000px; overflow:auto;">

        <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;width:100px">1</div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:300px;">2</div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;width:100px;">3</div>

    </div>
</div>
```